# No such file to load -- FasterCSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, passenger, web-deployment, fastercsv

This problem has been bugging me for hours already.  I am deploying a Rails3 App in a shared hosting site.  I have been able to run the site on my local Ubuntu. It works well. But as I try to deploy it online, it does not work well. So I think it may have something to do with the versions.  Also, I am not using this gem in any of my modules. The error message is as follows:

```
A source file that the application requires, is missing.
It is possible that you didn't upload your application files correctly. Please check whether all your application files are uploaded.
A required library may not installed. Please install all libraries that this application requires.
Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.

Error message:
No such file to load -- FasterCSV
Exception class:
LoadError
```

Backtrace:

```
#   File    Line    Location
0   /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    306 in `depend_on'
1   /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb    214 in `require_dependency'
2   /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb    417 in `eager_load!'
3   /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb    416 in `each'
4   /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb    416 in `eager_load!'
5   /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb    414 in `each'
6   /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb    414 in `eager_load!'
7   /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb  51  
8   /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb 30  in `instance_exec'
9   /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb 30  in `run'
10  /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb 55  in `run_initializers'
11  /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb 54  in `each'
12  /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb 54  in `run_initializers'
13  /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb   96  in `initialize!'
14  /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb  30  in `send'
15  /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.1.4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb  30  in `method_missing'
16  /home/dev/project/config/environment.rb 15  
17  config.ru   3   in `require'
18  config.ru   3   
19  /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb    51  in `instance_eval'
20  /home/dev/project/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.6/lib/rack/builder.rb    51  in `initialize'
21  config.ru   1   in `new'
22  config.ru   1
```

Ruby -v returns

```
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-02-18 patchlevel 334) [x86_64-linux]
```

Rails -v returns

```
Rails 3.1.4
```

I am deploying the app using Phusion Passenger.

Any help will do. Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

Here's the config.ru

```
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)
run project::Application
```

Environment.rb

```
# Load the rails application

#require 'will_paginate'
require 'rubygems'
require 'composite_primary_keys'
require 'logger'
require 'json'
#require 'composite_primary_keys'
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)



# Initialize the rails application
Dealmap::Application.initialize!
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2', '0.3.11'
#gem 'typus'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'geokit'
gem 'composite_primary_keys'
gem "rake", "0.8.7"
gem 'geocoder'
gem 'htmlentities'
gem 'json'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem "meta_search",    '>= 1.1.0.pre'
gem "nifty-generators", :group => :development
gem 'fastercsv'

gem 'gmaps4rails'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

gem "mocha", :group => :test
```

NOTE: I explicitly changed the project name to 'project'. Also, I recently added the `gem 'fastercsv'` line in the Gemfile after the error showed.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you paste-in the `config.ru`, `Gemfile` and `config/environment.rb` files? Are all the gems installed on your hosted machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked for help from the support. It seems that the error was that I was pointing to the wrong app version in my .htaccess.

Problem was solved.